# MariaDB is not starting even after port has been change

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

Can any body tell how backup database without mysql start.
Mysql error log is below

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 64M, instances = 1, chunk size = 64M
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 47063; transaction id 9
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210910 23:59:01
2021-09-10 23:59:01 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's MySQL? `10.4.14` sounds like a MariaDB version.

Comment: If `mysqld` is not running, you can back up a database any way you want, e.g. with `tar` or `zip` or whatever. I don't know why `mysqld` isn't starting for you. The log you show doesn't include any errors or warnings.

Comment: i copy ibdata1 file and database related folder to new xampp folder. but i did not work

Comment: This doesn't feel like a code-problem per se. Have you tried https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: this looks like your server has started normally, no need for dba